# mongodb c++ driver on ubuntu

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake, c++14, mongo-cxx-driver

I am trying to test mongodb c++ driver on Ubuntu 16.04.

The driver is installed in `${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb/`
and the test is in `${Devfolder}/testMongoDb/`.

The code was compliled and tested using:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb/lib
c++ --std=c++11 test.cpp -o test $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx)
```

Then I want to use mongodb driver in my CMake project.

```
ugitho@ugitho:projects$ tree -L 3
.
├── sdk
│   └── mongodb
│       ├── bin
│       ├── include
│       ├── lib
│       └── share
├── testMongo
│   ├── a.out
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   ├── cmongodb
│   │   └── Makefile
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── test
│   └── test.cpp
```

But I got the following error:

```
    ugitho@ugitho:build$ cmake ..
    LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/include/mongocxx/v_noabi;/home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
    LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES = LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARY_PATH-NOTFOUND;LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARY_PATH-NOTFOUND
    LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
    LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES = LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARY_PATH-NOTFOUND
    CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
    Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
    LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARY_PATH
        linked by target "cmongodb" in directory 
/home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/testMongoDb
        linked by target "cmongodb" in directory 
/home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/testMongoDb
    LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARY_PATH
        linked by target "cmongodb" in directory 
/home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/testMongoDb

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/testMongoDb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

edited*:

Here are `CMakeLists.txt` and `test.cpp`.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(cmongodb)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb)

#find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
#find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(LIBMONGOCXX REQUIRED libmongocxx)
pkg_check_modules(LIBBSONCXX REQUIRED libbsoncxx)
message("LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES = ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES}")

message("LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES = ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES}")

set(COMMON_LIBRARIES ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES} ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES})

set(SOURCE_FILES test.cpp)

add_executable(cmongodb ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(cmongodb PUBLIC ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(cmongodb PUBLIC ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(cmongodb ${COMMON_LIBRARIES})
```

**test.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char **) {
  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
  mongocxx::instance inst{};
  mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

  bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

  auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
  document << "hello"
           << "world";

  collection.insert_one(document.view());
  auto cursor = collection.find({});

  for (auto &&doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea about what I missed here?

Updates:

with the new CMakeLists.txt, there are no more cmake errors.

```
ugitho@ugitho:build$ cmake ..
-- Checking for module 'libmongocxx'
--   Found libmongocxx, version 3.4.0
-- Checking for module 'libbsoncxx'
--   Found libbsoncxx, version 3.4.0
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/shared
LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/include/mongocxx/v_noabi;/home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES = mongocxx;bsoncxx
LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/sdk/mongodb/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES = bsoncxx
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/testMongoDb/build
[1]+  Done                    gedit /home/ugitho/NGUYENKHAC/projects/testMongoDb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
```

The errors are now on make level:

```
ugitho@ugitho:build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target cmongodb
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmongodb.dir/test.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable cmongodb
/opt/llvm/x86_64/6.0.0.g631a/bin/ld: error: unable to find library -lmongocxx
/opt/llvm/x86_64/6.0.0.g631a/bin/ld: error: unable to find library -lbsoncxx
/opt/llvm/x86_64/6.0.0.g631a/bin/ld: error: unable to find library -lbsoncxx
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cmongodb] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmongodb.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

UPDATE *** 27/12/2018

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(cmongodb)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DIRECTORY)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PARENT_DIR}/sdk/mongodb)
message("CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)
set(MongoDb_INCLUDE_DIR ${PARENT_DIR}/sdk/mongodb/include)
include_directories(${MongoDb_INCLUDE_DIR}/mongocxx/v_noabi 
                    ${MongoDb_INCLUDE_DIR}/bsoncxx/v_noabi)

set(SOURCE_FILES test.cpp)
add_executable(cmongodb ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(cmongodb  ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES} 
                                ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES})
```

I managed to compile using this CMakeLists.txt.

new project config will be coming soon.
{GTest & Boost & MongoDb C++ Driver}

Thank you!!

Comment: The error message doesn't correspond to the `CMakeLists.txt` you show. Using `find_package` you search for "libbsoncxx", but the error message corresponds to searched package "libbsoncxx-static". Please, show the **actual code** and the **error message** it produces.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I've updated the error message.

Comment: [They said](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/966#issuecomment-352666948) `libbsoncxx` is a part of MongoDB. Probably, you need to hint CMake about MongoDB installation directory, e.g. by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` *environment* variable to `${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb`. If this doesn't help, try to find one of the files, listed in the error message (`libbsoncxxConfig.cmake` or `libbsoncxx-config.cmake`) under your MongoDB installation directory.

Comment: Adding 

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${Devfolser}sdk/mongodb)


and trying to logs:
message("LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES = ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES}")
 
message("LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES = ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES}")

but apparently, it doesn't work:

Comment: LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb/include/mongocxx/v_noabi;${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES = LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARY_PATH-NOTFOUND;LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARY_PATH-NOTFOUND
LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${Devfolder}/sdk/mongodb/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES = LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARY_PATH-NOTFOUND

Comment: Comments a badly suited for multiline code. Better, update the question post with additional info. So, setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` helps at least partially - it finds include directories, but not the libraries. BTW, in your original code you use `LIBMONGOCXX_STATIC_LIBRARIES` - probably, you should examine value of that variable instead of `LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES` one. (I don't know which variable should be used actually).

Comment: Sorry @Tsyvarev! I updated the CmakeLists.txt and the logs.

Comment: For future reference, after you added the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` but still got the linker error: `unable to find library -lbsoncxx`, this was because the linker did not know the path to bsoncxx. You could have used the `{LIBBSON_CXX_LINKER}` variable, which includes the absolute path [see here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html?highlight=s). That being said, using `find_package` as you did, seems preferable to using PkgConfig anyway.